# Red 5 works with all the demo apps, but when I try to add my own, it breaks. What's going on?

Tags: java, ant, red5

I installed Red 5 1.0 media server on my Windows 7 computer - hoping to use it for development before deploying to a server.  With great difficulty, I got the server up and running.  I am able to install the sample apps at localhost:5080 and they work.  For example, I am able to record video from my webcam using the sample apps.

Now, I want to write my own Java app for Red 5.  I've found a couple of tutorials, but none of them works. E.g.:

- http://blog.cirtex.com/2010/06/21/creating-an-application-with-flash-and-red5-is-simple-with-this-tutorial/
- http://sunil-gupta.blogspot.com/2007/03/how-to-create-sample-application-using.html

None of these fully works on its own, but I managed to cobble together a composite of these into a simple demo app that compiles fine in Eclipse or ANT, has a JAR file, and a directory structure that looks just like the demos.

Here's the funny thing.  When I copy this into the webapps directory and restart the service, ALL of the demos break.  (To restart, I'm just using Services Manager in Admin tools.)  The server still responds on port 5080 and shows the sample webpage -- but none of the media works.  All of the demo apps throw an error along the lines of "Can't connect", and even the welcome movie doesn't play.

This is the case with every home-made application I've dropped in there -- even the simplest Hello World app.

**So:  Can anybody help me figure out what's going on?**

Also, what's the latest tutorial, demo, etc. for 1.0.  Everything I can find seems to apply to older versions and it's extremely hard to put it together into any coherent picture of how Red5 works.

By the way, I installed Red5 using the installer for Windows -- not building it on the machine.  I'm only trying to build the apps on the machine and copy them into the running server.

Thanks for any help you can provide.  You'd be a life saver!

Answer (score 0):

I also tried installing red5 1.0 RC version. None of the demos worked. Then I stuck to the red5 0.9 final version. It works fine. Now trying to develop something even though red5 has bad documentation. This was the best I could find. But it was done in 2007 :) http://dl.fancycode.com/red5/api/overview-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

For your development machine (where youre building your red5 app), I suggest that you download the server "trunk". In the download you will find two files that will help you create a new red5 project: util.xml and project.zip. To use these, simply type this on the command line in the trunk directory:

`ant -f util.xml`

This will give you the usage options. Once you have the skeleton created you import the project into eclipse and go to town.
For addtional help you can post here on stacktrace, subscribe to the users list ( http://groups.google.com/group/red5interest ), use the forums ( http://www.red5.org/forums/ ), or the wiki ( http://wiki.red5.org/ ).

Lastly, another option is the eclipse plugin which you can find here: http://wiki.red5.org/wiki/Red5Plugin